# Using VBA to filter on date range and input named cell value in table

Tags: excel, vba

I have variable named cells which the end user will populate.  Start date = "VarStartDate", End Date = "VarEndDate", and a percentage variable = "AddVariationPer".  I need to populate a table column.  Table = "Projection".  table column = "Additional Variation" with the value inserted in "AddVariationPer".  When the column "2021 Date" is between "VarStartDate" and "VarEndDate".  I have been coding around in circles.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question - but why VBA?
= IF(And([2021 Date]>VarStartDate,[2021 Date]<VarEndDate),AddVariationPer,0)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your feedback!  The reason I think an IF statement won't work is the AddVariationPer could be updated throughout the year at different different times for different date ranges.  When the end user updates VarStartDate, VarEndDate, and AddVariationPer... I need the other updates to these variables to remain in their cells and only be overwritten if a new AddVariationPer was inputted for that same date..

Comment: Then you need VBA. You can still use this formula and for the cells that need to "frozen" you do  Range("cell").value = Range("cell").value  which copies the result of the formula into the cell